# How can i insert(or modify) struct to ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRUCT>> in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

The records "event_params" is array of struct

And values are also struct totally event_params structure type is

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRUCT(string_value, int_value, float_value, double_value)>
```

I want to add struct(or modify) to  ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRUCT>> in BigQuery Table.

### Problem 1

**This is a table to solve the problem**

[image]

**This is what i want to be.**

[image]

These queries didn't work

```
ARRAY_CONCAT(event_params, [(new_data_key, new_input_data_value, null, null, nul)]
```

or

```
ARRAY_CONCAT(event_params, [(new_data_key, (new_input_data_value, null, null, nul))]
```

And Error message is

```
No matching signature for function ARRAY_CONCAT for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>>, ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING, INT64, ...>>. Supported signature: ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY, [ARRAY, ...])
```

Should anyone tell me Answer Query??

Thank you in advance for your reply.

### Problem 2 (Not Solved)

Is it possible change data in ARRAY<STRING, STRUCT>?

ex) [Based on Figure 1 of the original article]

**change event_params.key & event_params.value.int_value**

```
# value.string_value
k6(original) -> k7 (what i want just change k6 -> k6-1)

# value.int_value
1(original) -> 3 (what i want is original * 3)
```

I handled this problem using UNNEST rows and then NEST them again. (I think it is very long and not good answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to update the entire array field. Use [ARRAY_CONCAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#combining_arrays):

```
update my_dataset.my_table
set event_params = ARRAY_CONCAT(
  event_params,
  [(new_data_key, (new_input_data_value, null, null, nul))]
)
```

Explicitly specifying type can help:

```
update my_dataset.my_table
set event_params = ARRAY_CONCAT(
  event_params,
  ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, double_value FLOAT64>>>[(new_data_key, (new_input_data_value, null, null, nul))]
)
```

Comment: It did not work. Because columns (event_params.values.xxx) is STRUCT<STRUCT>.
THE ERROR MESSAGE is "No matching signature for function ARRAY_CONCAT for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>>, ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING, INT64, ...>>. Supported signature: ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY, [ARRAY, ...])".

I think the answer query is more complicated. Thx!

Comment: Sorry, updated. If there will be any error messages, please post them.

Comment: It works, You are my hero! Geron. Can i ask on more question? I updated, Please note my question 2. Thx a lot!

Comment: Updating elements in an array is not so convenient because it is not a usual use-case for the BigQuery. If you need to do lots of updates consider using BigTable instead. But maybe somebody knows more beautiful approach than unnest-nest. Try asking a new question (few will take a look at an already answered question).

Comment: Got it, Thx for your help! Have a nice day :)